# USING ASP.NET receiving error: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, web

I am receiving Server Error in '/' Application when I run my .aspx page in my local host. It is complaining that it cannot find the file that im trying to inherit within my .aspx file. The line in my file looks like this:

```
< Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="ANDDI1.WebForm1" >
```

I have the .aspx file and the .aspx.vb file in the folder that im trying to pull up. For some reason its complaining about the inherits file. My project name is ANDDI1 but I don't see that file anywhere in my project. I do not know what to include in my localhost folder so this doesn't occur. Any ideas of what exactly im suppose to include in my localhost folder so I can run my ASP.NET code? Right now I currently have WebForm1.aspx and WebForm1.aspx.vb in my local host and my local host spits out the Server error which is complaining about the inherits file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you are certain there is a `WebForm1` class under the `ANDDI1` namespace in the WebForm1.aspx.vb file?

Comment: Do I have to inherit? Bc it is not in my aspx.vb file. I have no idea how to add that

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this in your code-behind, there is a direct relationship between your .aspx and aspx.vb files:

```
Namespace ANDDI1
    Class WebForm1
        //Event handlers and methods go here
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb"` in your @Page directive to this `CodeFile="WebForm1.aspx.vb"` and all will be well.